# How to boot GParted Live from USB-C drive on a Dell Precision 7540 Laptop?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, gparted, usb-c

I want to partition my system (to install dual boot option for Windows/Ubuntu) using GParted. I downloaded and installed the GParted ISO Image and installed it on an USB (C) Stick using UNetbootin.

However, when I reboot and enter the boot menu (pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>), the USB device doesn't show up.

In advance I prepared the following in the BIOS:

- disabled Secure Boot
- chose Fast Boot Option: thorough
- enabled Thunderbold Boot Support

I tried out both USB-C ports on my laptop and a different USB Stick but nothing lets the USB device show up in the boot menu. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

UNetBootin is known to have issues when creating bootable USB stick (see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB_flash_installation_medium#Using_UNetbootin) [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758658/creating-a-usb-media-using-unetbootin-isnt-recognized-as-booting-media) and [here](https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/issues/90)). If you're on windows, try [rufus](https://rufus.ie/). Otherwise any of the method on [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/USB_flash_installation_medium) should work too.